# Pearson multiple correlation upper bound

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pearson-r

Suppose we have multiple independent variables y<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>,...  along with their Pearson correlations r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub>,... related to a dependent variable x. (Assume that we do not know the correlations between the independent variables).

Then the lower bound of the multiple correlation is (AFAIK) the largest of the correlations absolute values.

What is the upper bound of the multiple correlation in terms of r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub>,... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with two variables.

Suppose $\phi_1, \phi_2, \eta$ are uncorrelated variables, each with mean 0 and variance 1.

Set $y_1 = \alpha_1 \phi_1 + \eta$ ,$y_2 = \alpha_2 \phi_2 - \eta$, and $x = \alpha_1 \phi_1 + \alpha_2 \phi_2 = y_1 + y_2$.

Then $E\left[y_1^2\right] = 1 + \alpha_1^2$, $E\left[y_2^2\right] = 1 + \alpha_2^2$, $E\left[x^2\right] = \alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2$, $E\left[y_1 x\right] = \alpha_1^2$, and $E\left[y_2 x\right] = \alpha_2^2$.

From this we have that

$\mbox{corr}(y_1, x) = \frac{\alpha_1^2}{\sqrt{1 + \alpha_1^2}\sqrt{\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2}}$

and

$\mbox{corr}(y_2, x) = \frac{\alpha_2^2}{\sqrt{1 + \alpha_2^2}\sqrt{\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2}}$

Clearly, the multiple correlation is 1 (as $x = y_1 + y_2$), but looking at the above two equations, they are solvable for $r_1$ and $r_2$. So it doesn't look there is a nontrivial upper bound.

I think this can be extended to an arbitrary number of variables (by making each $y_i$ include $\frac{1}{n - 1} \eta$ for ($i = 1, ..., n -1$), and $y_n$ include $-\eta$), but the terms got a bit messy.

Comment: thanks for the answer. When you say that there is no nontrivial upper bound, do you mean that the trivial upper bound is 1?

Comment: @Ury Yes, that is the meaning. Node that $x$ is a linear combination of the $y$s.